ISO to GOD format in Linux
In order to play my Xbox360 games on Xenia, I've to convert my game from ISO format to GOD format as it is suggested in Xenia's documentation. 
I made the ISO file proposed here : sudo cat /dev/sr0 > /home/user/xbox360game.iso. I'm not sure this is the good way to make .iso file from xbox's dvd games, tell me if I am wrong please.
First try : using iso2god with wine 
After extracting Iso2God.exe and xextool.exe in the folder iso2god, then running Iso2God.exe through wine I've got this issue :
(base) user@machine:~/iso2god$ wine Iso2God.exe
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0090:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0090:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0090:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0090:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0114:err:module:fixup_imports_ilonly mscoree.dll not found, IL-only binary L"Iso2God.exe" cannot be loaded
0114:err:module:loader_init Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\user\\iso2god\\Iso2God.exe" failed, status c0000135

I found this in wine's forum about the issue. I obtained the same :
(base) user@machine:~/.wine$ find ./ -iname "*mscoree.dll*"
./drive_c/windows/syswow64/mscoree.dll
./drive_c/windows/system32/mscoree.dll

But I did not try the proposed solution WINEPREFIX=$HOME/GarminExpr winetricks --force -q dotnet48 because I don't understand well what are prefixes and how to use it (I prefer to avoid to make more mess than there's now and asking for your advices).
Second try : using iso2god-rs
(base) user@machine:~/iso2god$ wine iso2god-x86_64-linux
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0094:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0094:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0094:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0094:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
Le programme n'a pas pu être lancé, ou aucun programme n'est associé au fichier 
spécifié.
ShellExecuteEx a échoué: Fichier introuvable.

Translation : The program could not be launched, or this file does not have a program associated with it.
ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.
So, is there a third way ? Or what must I do for the first/second try ?

Versions:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64 bits
wine: wine-9.0
Iso2God : 1.3.7
Iso2God-rs : 1.7.0

